# What is not being deallocated in this Google maps fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I've got an app which is quite intensive in terms of memory and i'm trying to get all I can. I've noticed something which I can't work out, Google maps is keeping its allocation of memory even after (I think) i'm getting rid of it.

**Before Google Maps is called:**
[image: Before GoogleMaps is called]

**After Google Maps is called:**
[image: After Google Maps is called]

**Returned from Google Maps with back button:**
[image]

**Returned from Google Maps with on info window press button:**
(the slightly higher number is just due to the fact I included a couple of methods more to include a marker to return)
[image]

As you can see, it's retaining a lot of the memory. So i'll show you how this is working:

Google Maps is not actually called, but a container for Google Maps is, and it's below:

```
public class GoogleMapsAndBookmarksContainer extends ActionBarActivity {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
public ArrayList frameListContainer;
public HashMap<String, HashMap> bookmarkInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps_and_bookmarks_container);

    frameListContainer = (ArrayList) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayListWithFrameAttributes");
    bookmarkInfo = (HashMap) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("hashmapWithBookmarks");

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

// The first tab is the google maps fragment which i'll include below

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Google Maps", null),
            GoogleMapsFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Bookmarks", null),
            BookmarksFragment.class, null);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
     /// **** THIS WAS JUST ADDED A LOSS FOR WHAT IT COULD BE RETAINING ****
    mTabHost = null;
    frameListContainer = null;
    bookmarkInfo = null;
}

// access for fragments
public HashMap getBookmarkInfo(){
    return bookmarkInfo;
}

public ArrayList getFrameAttributesArrayList(){
    return frameListContainer;
}
}
```

I managed to remove everything from my class but this and still the problem remain:

public class GoogleMapsFragment extends Fragment {

```
private GoogleMap map;
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_maps, container, false);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            map = googleMap;
            initMap();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
//        frameListContainer = ((GoogleMapsAndBookmarksContainer) this.getActivity()).getFrameAttributesArrayList();
//        bookmarkInfo = ((GoogleMapsAndBookmarksContainer) this.getActivity()).getBookmarkInfo();
//        markerToFrameAndRoute = new HashMap<Marker, String[]>();
}




@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapFragment = null;
    System.gc();
    map = null; // I did add this in an edit, but it was mistakenly taken away when I was cutting it up, sorry
}
}
```

So, is this solvable? I can't work out what it is that it's retaining. I did notice if I keep going back on Google Maps and off it, it is garbage collecting it, so it's not a memory leak.

**edit**: have tried map.clear();  still keeps the memory

Comment: call `System.gc()` if you move away from Google Maps.

Comment: Where do you mean, in the activity i'm returning to?

Comment: System.gc runs garbage collector, when you move away from Google Maps means if your are switching your screen from google Maps, run this. This will run Garbage Collector.

Comment: Although it is not guaranteed that GC will run on this call, but will eventually run.

Comment: in my onDestroy, I have a System.gc() already, do you mean you want me to place one in the activity too, or just move it to after the new map.clear();

Comment: If you're pretty sure that code looks fine i'm happy to continue on if it's eventually going to be garbage collected. The real reason was that I was investigating a memory leak, and I noticed this at the beginning when I cut all the fat. I think map.clear will solve my memory leak problem though as I think it had something to do with the poly lines being retained.  Thanks.

Comment: its a good idea to clear you map as soon as you done with it.

Comment: Thanks, if you want put about the GC eventually running in an answer and i'll accept. I thought it was an instant thing.

Comment: thats not needed. if you app runs out of Ram it will throw `Out of Memory` error, most of the time this will happen if you have large images which exhausts heap and available memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Just clear map 

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    map.clear();
}
```

Comment: Hey, it's not working sadly :( same thing happens, 9.97mb before and 10mb after.

Comment: having you check ondestroy call or not?

Comment: Yes with a system out, that is what my first check was. It doesn't look like it's being called until I am back on the other view though... Maybe that could be a reason?

Comment: I don't know how I could speed it up though, when I return with the back button.. I wait like 2 seconds and then it system outs the OnDestroy call..

Comment: Any other ideas to what it could be? Do you perhaps have a google maps app which you can try this too with? Maybe nobody notices the 4mb retain.

Comment: Thanks anyway man, I think this will solve another problem which was the main reason as to why I found this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One probable solution to this problem may be to use a retained fragment using [setRetainInstance(boolean retain)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29). In this process the map fragment wont destroy and recreate itself dumping a lot of memory, instead it will just retain the memory when it is needed, when you switch map fragment back and forth (by pressing back button).

```
public class RetainMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // First incarnation of this activity.
        mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    } else {
        // Reincarnated activity. The obtained map is the same map instance in the previous
        // activity life cycle. There is no need to reinitialize it.
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
```

Another solution to this may be to use a [Otto event bus](http://square.github.io/otto/) which is designed to decouple different parts of your application while still allowing them to communicate efficiently.

Hope this Helps!!